# How to get backData from sap.m.NavContainer

Tags: javascript, sapui5

According to doc [API](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainer.html#back) we can send the data from another page to previous page as below

```
oNavContiner.back({
   dataToSend: data
});
```

I have attached the event as below

```
<NavContainer id="navContainer" afterNavigate ="afterSelectedReferenceLayers">
```

in XML View, and in the controller the following method is added but data is not coming:

```
afterSelectedReferenceLayers : function(oControlEvent) {
    if (oControlEvent.getParameter('direction') === 'back') {
        console.log(oControlEvent.data);
    }
}
```

Please help me how to get this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the API, [afterNavigate](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainer.html#event:afterNavigate) does not contain data sent from Nav.to and Nav.back. But its the onBeforeShow method of the the view which contains the data.

So in the onBeforeShow method, there are 2 parameters which contains data sent via .to and .back:

1. data: The "beforeShow" event on the target page will contain data object as "data" property sent with `.to()` method.
2. backData: The "beforeShow" event on the target page will contain data object as "backData" property sent with `.back()` method.

So, I would modify your code as below:

**Step** : Add onBeforeShow to pages ( where I need back handling)

```
    //this.byId('p1') here refers to my page where I want onBeforeShow associated.
    this.byId('p1').addEventDelegate({
        'onBeforeShow':function(evt) {

            if (evt.direction == 'to') {
                var oData = evt.data;
                console.log(oData);
            } else if (evt.direction === 'back') {
                var oData = evt.backData;
                console.log(oData);
            }
        }
    });
```

Let me know if you need additional information.